# AD account with SP user profile synchronization issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, synchronisation, azure-ad

I have two problems.

1. I created new user in AD. Then make a full synchronization in SP central administration.
   After that go to User profiles and searched that user.But user didn't find.
   ( I didn't add any permissions in AD account)
2. I updated another user property in AD and made a full synchronization.After that view that user in SP, but updated values not there.
   Here is the way I used to map AD account attribute with SP user profile property.

   - Get the AD user attribute name and add it to SP attribute section.

here is the screenshot

[image]

Office telephone is SP property and telephoneNumber is AD attribute name.

I think this is synchronization issue.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: how much time you waited before start the full sync? did you run incremental sync after full?

Comment: full sync did after my changes. and many times did full sync and incremental sync

Answer (score 0):

Go to user profile service application->Configure Synchronization connections, check if the connection is configured correctly.

Update the authentication account in the connection settings, and start a full sync, then check the result.

Comment: what did you mean by authentication account? is it account name?
This is recently worked. It's not working correctly for my changes only.I meant, created new account and newly mapped properties only not working.Previous accounts can see